# Looking for ways to optimize this code

Tags: c, loops, optimization

The following code is part of an edge detect program:

```
void detect_optimized(int width, int height, int threshold)
{
    int x, y;
    int tmp;`
    int w = width--;
    int h = height--;

for (y = 1; y < w; y++)
    for (x = 1; x < h; x++)
    {
        tmp = mask_product(mask,a,x,y,0);
        if (tmp>255)
            tmp = 255;
        if (tmp<threshold)
            tmp = 0;
        c[x][y][0] = 255-tmp;

        tmp = mask_product(mask,a,x,y,1);
        if (tmp>255)
            tmp = 255;
        if (tmp<threshold)
            tmp = 0;
        c[x][y][1] = 255-tmp;

        tmp = mask_product(mask,a,x,y,2);
        if (tmp>255)
            tmp = 255;
        if (tmp<threshold)
            tmp = 0;
        c[x][y][2] = 255-tmp;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to implement blocking with the following code but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: Very minor, but you can use `else if` for the second `if` in each pair.

Comment: I'm assuming that `threshold` should always be less than 255.

Comment: Why `int w = width--;` and then no further use for `width` and so no point decrementing? Small efficiency by using `width` and `height` as the loop limit variables, and removing `w` and `h`, such as `for (y = 1; y < width; y++)`. You can also gain some efficiency by writing the special cases directly into the array (instead of doing a subtraction), followed by `else`.

Comment: `byte c[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL][NUM_COLORS];`

Comment: Oddly similar to [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505077/speedup-and-optimize-c-function)

Comment: What is the range of  `threshold`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the loops to get a better cache utilization. This should speedup your code significantly (especially for large data).

```
for (x = 1; x < h; x++)
    for (y = 1; y < w; y++)
```

Another substantial benefit can be reached by distributing the loop iterations over multiple threads to exploit multicore architectures. Using `OpenMP` this is can be reached with a single compiler directive as follows.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(y, tmp)
for (x = 1; x < h; x++)
    for (y = 1; y < w; y++)
```

Other optimizations are usually done by the compiler. Make sure to use appropriate compiler flags like `-O2` and don't bother with low level adaptation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Offer the following candidate

1. Avoid `if()`s at the price of `*`.  Various pipelined platforms will benefit.
2. Swap `x,y` order
3. Decrement so end of loop test is against 0.
4. Avoid recomputing `c[x][y]`

Assume need to go though all colors.

Of course, YMMV.

```
for (x = h-1; x > 0; x--) {
  byte *p = &c[x][w-1][NUM_COLORS-1];

  for (y = w-1; y > 0; y--) {
    for (int z = NUM_COLORS-1; z >= 0; z--) {
      int tmp = mask_product(mask,a,x,y,z);
      *p = (255 - tmp*(tmp>=threshold))*(tmp <=255);
      p--;
     }
  }
}
```